# Backbone Displaying collections (collection of collections maybe?)

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

js file;

```
var dataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                dataID : 'unknown',
                text : 'unknown'
            }
        });
        var LinkCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : dataModel
        });
```

lets say collection size is 8. I want to display 3 at a time. Due to the script's structure, i need to divide the collection items ito seperate divs.

html file;

```
<div class="item">
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #1
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #2
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #3
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
</div>


<div class="item">
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #4
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #5
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #6
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #7
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
<div class="carousel-subItem">  <-- Collection item #8
   <span>{{dataID}}</span> <br /> <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I am having hard time to create this html structure dynamically. (since the collection size can varies....  the structure should be completely dynamically etc;

```
 {{#each dataModel}}
    // code goes here, to create the above structure.. 
 {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this may help you:

```
<script type="text/tempalte" id="template">

<% var len = items.length, group = 3, i; %>
<% for (i = 0; i <len; i += 1) { %>
    <% if (i % group === 0) { %>
        <div class="item">
    <% } %>
        <div class="carousel-subItem"> 
            <span><%= items[i].dataID %></span> <br /> <span><%= items[i].text %></span>
        </div>
    <% if ((i % group === group-1) || (i === len -1)) { %>  
        </div>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
</script>
```

I was assuming you would like to use Underscore as you are using Backbone. The items collection looks something like this, which should be close to Backbones point of view:

```
var items = [
    { dataID : '1', text : 'bla' },
    { dataID : '2', text : 'blab' },
    { dataID : '3', text : 'gulp' },
    { dataID : '4', text : 'golp' },
    { dataID : '5', text : 'bla' }
];

// compiling the template
var template = _.template($('#template').html());
console.log(template(items));
```

The output looks like this:

```
<div class="item">

        <div class="carousel-subItem"> 
            <span>1</span> <br /> <span>bla</span>
        </div>



        <div class="carousel-subItem"> 
            <span>2</span> <br /> <span>blab</span>
        </div>



        <div class="carousel-subItem"> 
            <span>3</span> <br /> <span>gulp</span>
        </div>

        </div>



        <div class="item">

        <div class="carousel-subItem"> 
            <span>4</span> <br /> <span>golp</span>
        </div>



        <div class="carousel-subItem"> 
            <span>5</span> <br /> <span>bla</span>
        </div>

        </div>
```

I may add that a better approach would be to have an ItemView which renders the "carousel-subItem"-div and a CollectionView which takes care of combining the rendered ItemViews into a container. I think Backbone.Marionette offers just that. Maybe you would like to check it out. Of course, you could construct something like that on your own as well.

Comment: Why don't you move the logic to the render?

Comment: The Backbone `render` method, that way it could work with Handlebars templates like the OP has.

Comment: It looked more like a general question how to template the given task.